# Retrieve lowest/highest value in each group composed of the last N values in a list

Tags: r, max, grouping

I am using R, but solutions in other languages work too.

Suppose I have an numeric list (ordered, so that the actual order of continuous values in the list matters).

In each row, I want to retrieve the lowest/highest value in the group composed of the last N observations in the list itself.
For doing this, I understand that a double step solution may work:

1. create groups of N latest observations
2. find the min/max value in the group

However, while the second point is pretty straightforward, in the first one it is required to create groups of N **overlapping** observations (i.e. the last observation in one group, becomes the second last observation in the next group, etc.).

How can I code this dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `frollapply` from `data.table`?

```
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(A = 1:100,B = runif(100,100,200))
data[,`:=`(Min = frollapply(B,n=10,FUN=min), Max = frollapply(B,n=10,FUN=max)) ]
```

Or if you prefer predefined functions there is `roll_min` and `roll_max` from `RcppRoll`. These also offer more flexibility using the `by=` argument.